# Why was one of these locked and downvoted to oblivion, and the other remains active and open?

Tags: discussion

[In the films, was the portrayal of Captain America supposed to come across as gay?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170604/in-the-films-was-the-portrayal-of-captain-america-supposed-to-come-across-as-ga?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and

[Is Captain America gay?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114500/is-captain-america-gay)

I don't often come across questions that are locked, and I don't think I've ever come across a pair of questions like this.  Why is one locked and the other open, not marked as duplicate, and how did newer one not get voted into oblivion?  The newer one also has a YouTube video talking about the question.  The older one has many answers, each with many upvotes.

I don't think that during the 2 years between these questions the topic/politics of gay superheros has changed that much such that the audience has that different of an opinion, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Both received a considerable number of downvotes but the original was very heavily "opinion-based" whereas the latter one asked for specific evidence relating to his portrayal in the film series. Also, the original one was fairly offensive to pretty much every group; men, women, gay and straight.

Comment: There is a reason the second, open, question is by anon user. There was a considerable back lash to it and many comments were removed and it wasn't the question and premise was properly explained that the voting started to turn around.

Comment: "The premise of the question isn't bad, but the way you asked it is totally inappropriate."

Comment: In case you can't see, one is +35/-29 while the other is +11/-48.

Comment: By my read of merely the titles, the questions are clearly quite different. There's a huge difference between asking about a character and asking about how a character was portrayed.

Answer (score 15):

I locked the first one because it had entered into a [close/reopen and delete/undelete war](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/114500/revisions) which showed no signs of stopping. (While the same user can't participate in closing or reopening a question more than once, apparently there's no limit on the number of times one user can vote to delete or undelete the same post.)

As for why it was so controversial (very controversial indeed, to the point where at least one user threatened to quit the site if the question was allowed to remain): some of the **phrasing** made the question seem trolling and/or offensive. For example:

- > First, if you are thinking that this question is a joke or troll, I'd like to welcome you to the 21st century when the mankind is discussing legality of gay marriages.
- > Although his age is 80+, he is still young. Yet, he doesn't have a girlfriend and he doesn't show any interest in girls. Even when Black Widow kissed him, he didn't try to drag her to bed.

I'd rather *not* get into details of discussing that particular question, OP's intent, and all the history surrounding it. Suffice it to say that the community reacted very negatively due to *other* things than the simple question "Is Captain America gay".

---

The second question was *also* controversial: although it has a positive score, that's split into **+35 / -29**. In fact I believe it was an attempt to ask the underlying (reasonable) question "Is Captain America gay" in a way that the community would accept. Unfortunately, it received backlash precisely because of the older question. It was even [closed as a duplicate and reopened](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/170604/revisions). There are 26 deleted comments on this question; a custom mod flag was raised calling it a troll question; it was even controversial enough that the OP disassociated it from their account.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the other question is incredibly distasteful with regards to the language used in terms of bridging on being NSFW. I'd legit be afraid to view that in a workplace or anywhere public or with children around.